# PHP: how to flush cookies

Tags: php, cookies, race-condition

Consider this example

*index.php*:

```
<script>
    var first = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var second = new XMLHttpRequest();

    first.open('POST', 'foo.php');
    second.open('POST', 'bar.php');

    first.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        console.log(document.cookie);
    });

    first.send();
    second.send();
</script>
```

*foo.php*:

```
<?php
    setcookie('foo', 'foo');
    sleep(5);
```

*bar.php*:

```
<?php
    setcookie('foo', 'bar');
```

Is there any way to make `foo == 'bar'` in the cookie when both requests finish, instead of `foo == 'foo'`?

Edit: I suppose I need to elaborate on why this is a problem.

I am trying to implement a [library](https://github.com/mebjas/CSRF-Protector-PHP) to prevent *cross site request forgery* on my site. This library requires that a unique token be sent along with any `POST` request from the client. To accomplish this, the library stores the expected token in the `SESSION` and then sends the token to the browser using `setcookie`.

This is a problem for me because I am using a custom session store, which is a table in a MySQL database. If two `POST` requests come from the same client within a short enough time, this creates a race condition where the expected value in the database for the third request is always the token generated by the request that is SENT last, but the token that is used by the browser is from the request that COMPLETES last. If request 1 takes longer to complete than request 2, the cookie and the database do not match for request 3.

That's why I asked this particular question. I know that `header` in PHP immediately sends any header information to the browser, regardless of output buffering, and cookies are essentially just headers. Why, then, can't I enforce this behaviour specifically with cookies?

I realize all of this could have been avoided by not sending multiple requests so close together, but I don't have the ability to change that in any reasonable amount of time, and simply queuing the requests to send only after the previous completes will negatively impact my users' experience quite a bit.

Comment: This could probably be done with pure JS using document.cookie, look a the examples in https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Do it on the JS side, using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all. Why split up the two calls like this, though?

Comment: The cookie needs to come from PHP. This is just a simplified example of a larger problem that I'm experiencing.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: I'm aware there are alternate ways to prevent CSRF. I just want to know if what I'm asking is possible, but thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the token for CSRF prevention don't have to change each request, so I'm not sure why this is a problem. Just generate a token at log in and stick to it.

More importantly, a Cookie **will not prevent CSRF** because Cookies are sent for forged requests too! This is no CSRF prevention. You should be sending this token with the POST data, typically as a hidden field in the form.

Also, PHP already prevents race condition within the same session by default. If a script tries to `session_start()` a session that is already being used by another script, it will sleep until the other call is over or invokes a `session_write_close()`.

Comment: It really seems like the jury is still out on whether session-level tokens are adequate. I thought the consensus was that the per-request tokens are the safer approach if you're implementing from scratch, which I'm doing.

Comment: I also think I should explain more how the library works? The token that is sent to the server for validation is sent in the POST data along with the rest of the request, which it grabs from the cookie. The new token that will be used by the following request is what's sent via cookies.

Comment: And it was my belief that PHP sessions aren't blocking if you use a database instead of the default, which I'm doing. Regardless, I have simulated PHP's blocking functionality for sessions by using table locks, but I'm writing the session long before the request finishes. The problem, therefore, is not with the session, but with the cookie.

Comment: @JimmyP The jury isn't out, a simple test will prove that relying on session or Cookies to prevent CSRF doesn't work, it's simply illogical to think it would. All requests will forward Cookies that are set, aswell as the session that also relies on a Cookie. There is simply no reason to believe you can discriminate a legitimate call from a forged one from there. The only other approach is checking the HTTP Referer, but assuming a Referer will be set for all legitimate requests is not necessarily correct.

Comment: I still don't think you're quite understanding the concept of the library. First and foremost, the token is being sent FROM the browser TO the server in the body of all `HTTP` requests. What it does is override the `send` function for `XHR` to scrape the cookie for the token, append the token to the request body, then continue submitting the request. Once PHP receives the request and the request is of type `POST`, that token is removed from the cookie and replaced with a brand new one. When the browser goes to submit its next request it will scrape the cookie again, using the new token.

Comment: @JimmyP That's either still unsafe or a hacky solution. Even if you only set the Cookie at the time you actually POST, which is probably not what you are doing otherwise it would be easier to simply send the postkey as a field in the form, it is technically not guaranteed the legitimate request will be processed before a potential forged one that is submitted just at the wrong time. I suggest you go with what is known to be safe instead of using some sketchy Cookie/POST validation that as we can see has a lot of problems.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying about why it's unsafe. How would a cross site request affect a legitimate request at or near the same time?

Comment: @JimmyP It doesn't have to affect any legitimate request. It just has to request. Do you even know what a forged request is?

Comment: Yes, which is why I'm confused by what you're saying. I've said repeatedly that the token IS put into the request body, where it's then checked server side. If a forged request doesn't have the token IN ITS BODY or has an incorrect one then it gets rejected.

Comment: @JimmyP Then why are we talking about Cookies?

Comment: The library works like this: 1. User performs a `GET` for the page 2. A session is started and a token is generated and placed in the session array; at this point `setcookie` is also called, putting the token in the cookie 3. A `.js` file is appended to the response body along with a hidden input field. This `.js` overrides `XHR`'s `send` and `<form>` `onsubmit` to scrape the token from the cookie and append it to the request 4. When a new request is sent, repeat the process. If type is `POST`, check token; replace with new one in session and cookie if matches session, reject if not

Comment: @JimmyP Then just drop the part where you replace the token for a new one and it should be good enough. As I said on my answer, you don't need a new postkey for each request to make it safe. As long as there is no XSS on the site it will be impossible for a forged request to figure out the token even if it never changes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your original question is quite simply no, I'm afraid. You do not have sufficient control over the connections to enforce anything. As you write in your edit, setting the cookies is done via headers and this happens asynchronously.

Regarding your edited question: you can make this work by storing multiple tokens per client. That is, every time a new request comes in from a client, don't delete the current token, but only create a new one. The client side should then not only send the correct token, but also the correct "connection ID". This ID can simply be a counter for number of requests from a client.

Alternatively, you can opt to not refresh the token for AJAX requests, but only for normal page loads. Depending on how your site works, this may not be safe though.

Comment: I don't think the asynchronicity is the reason why this doesn't work, and token reuse is a huge security vulnerability that I'm not prepared to expose. Normal page loads are usually GET requests, and those rarely need protection from CSRF. The problem is with any type of POST, which includes AJAX, assuming you follow the paradigm.

Comment: Normally, the token is included in the page when the browser GETs it. It is then included in a subsequent POST for verification by the server. You can either allow parallel POSTs to use the same token, include multiple tokens in the page to start with, or serialize your POSTs and get a new token in every POST that the next POST can use. If those POSTs are fired quickly after one another, then I don't think that there is a big risk in using the same token for both requests.